# PUT update a TeamCity Configuration Parameter working from PostMan but not from Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, fluenttc

```
$url = "https://teamcity.myserver.io/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:SandboxPlayGround_WindowsForms1_Build/parameters/Version" 

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"

$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'text/plain')

$headers.Add("Origin", 'https://teamcity.myserver.io')

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body "2.3.1.0"
```

Gives me error:

```
[19:54:59][Step 2/6] Invoke-RestMethod : HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported
[19:54:59][Step 2/6]
[19:54:59][Step 2/6]
[19:54:59][Step 2/6]
[19:54:59][Step 2/6] type Status report
[19:54:59][Step 2/6] message Request method 'PUT' not supported
[19:54:59][Step 2/6] description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

But I can update Parameter value using the same URL and Headers from PostMan just fine.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set build configuration parameter using [FluentTc](https://github.com/QualiSystems/FluentTc) library using C#:

```
new RemoteTc()
  .Connect(_ => _.ToHost("teamcity.myserver.io")
    .AsUser("MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD"))
  .SetBuildConfigurationParameters(
    _ => _.Id("SandboxPlayGround_WindowsForms1_Build"),
    _ => _.Parameter("Version", "2.3.1.0") );
```

If needed you may call this code from Powershell using one of these techniques:
http://executeautomation.com/blog/calling-c-code-in-powershell-and-vice-versa/